# Add User To an Active Directory Group temporarily in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to figure out away to temporality assign a user to an AD group. I know in PowerShell there is a command called "MemberTimeToLive" so I'm trying to find something equivalent in python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Tried this out, thanks! Unfortunately the solution is not fully correct. TTL needs to be prepended to the user, not the group.

```py
 import ldap

 conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
 ldap_base = 'dc=example,dc=local'
 group_dn = 'CN=The Group,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
-user_dn =  b'CN=test1,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
+user_dn =  b'<TTL=60,CN=test1,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local>'
 conn.modify_s(
   group_dn, [
     (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user_dn],)],
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is! You just need to encode TTL (in seconds) to the DN

```
 import ldap

 conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
 ldap_base = 'dc=example,dc=local'
-group_dn = 'CN=The Group,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
+group_dn = '<TTL=60,CN=The Group,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local>'
 user_dn =  b'CN=test1,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
 conn.modify_s(
   group_dn, [
     (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user_dn],)],
 )
```